# Problem with creating nested dynamic components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

```
$A.createComponent(
                    [
                    "c:LegalLegitimationDetails", 
                     [{
                    "accountId": accountId,
                    "contextData": component.get('v.contextData'),
                    "userId": userId,
                    "recordTypeId":component.get('v.legitimationRecordTypeId'),
                    "legitimationData":component.get('v.legitimationData')
                    }],
                    "c:LegitimationDeatils",
                    [{
                        "pageReferenceDispatcher":component.get('v.pageReference'),
                        "recordIdDispatcher":component.get('v.recordId')
                    }]
                    ],

                    function(content, status) {
                        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                            modalBody = content;
                            component.find('legalOverLayLib').showCustomModal({
                                header: titleLegitimation,
                                body: modalBody, 
                                showCloseButton: false,
                                closeCallback: function() {}
                        })
                   }
               })
```

I am trying to create two dynamic components but my call back function is never getting called.

My call back is not getting triggered, I get the error.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to contain the exact error message, as well as including an actual question. Instead of saying "please help", try to ask how to resolve a specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating multiple components then you will need to use

`$A.createComponents`

instead of

```
$A.createComponent
```

Also you are passing inputs to an component as array which is wrong.

```
                    [
                    "c:LegalLegitimationDetails", 
                     {
                    "accountId": accountId,
                    "contextData": component.get('v.contextData'),
                    "userId": userId,
                    "recordTypeId":component.get('v.legitimationRecordTypeId'),
                    "legitimationData":component.get('v.legitimationData')
                    },
                    "c:LegitimationDeatils",
                    {
                        "pageReferenceDispatcher":component.get('v.pageReference'),
                        "recordIdDispatcher":component.get('v.recordId')
                    }
                    ]
```

Input should be passed an object not an array.

You can see difference here .

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm